# Is it possible cache node.js view output as a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, caching, express

In PHP, I used to use [output buffering to cache the output](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/buffer/) and save it as a html file. I was wondering if the same could be done in node.js. The following is my route file:

```
module.exports = {

 index: function(section,page,req,res){
  var l = res.locals,  

  db = l.db,

  Promise = l.Promise,

  Promise.props({

       my: db.db.query('CALL fetchdata()'),

       amba: db.db.query("CALL fetchanother()")
  }).then(function(obj){ 

       return res.render(section+'.html',obj)

    }).then(function(data){

       console.log(data);

       l.fs.writeFile('index.html', data)

    }).catch(function (error) {

       console.log(error);
    })
 }
};
```

`return res.render(section+'.html',obj)` isn't working. `console.log(data)` returns "undefined" in the console and the html file doesn't have anything but the word "undefined". I have also tried this:

```
    .then(function(obj){ 
       var cache
       res.render(section+'.html',obj,function(k,content){
           res.send(content)
           cache = content
       })
       return cache;
    }).then(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       l.fs.writeFile('index.html', data)

    })
```

It is still undefined. Is there a way to cache the view result as a html file?

Comment: Note that Express already implements caching of views, though it's typically disabled for development -- [`"view cache"` option](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st snippet, `data` is `undefined` because that's the value that `res.render(...)` returns.

Typically (depending on the exact Promise implementation), any value other than another `Promise` returned in a `.then()` calback will be treated as a resolution value. So, the following 2 snippets are roughly equivalent.

```
.then(function () {
    return undefined;
})
```

```
.then(function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve(undefined);
    });
})
```

To receive the `html`, since `res.render()` is asynchronous and doesn't provide a Promise itself, you'll want to wrap it in a Promise so it's waited on:

```
.then(function(obj){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        res.render(section+'.html', obj, function (err, html) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(html);
        });
    });
}).then(function(data){
    // ...
```

**Note**: The above snippets are compatible with [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and may require revisions if you're using a different implementation.

---

For the 2nd snippet, there's already a Q&A on SO with a good explanation:

> [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)